# Robotium : I want to Do data driven Testing using robotium?

Tags: java, android, automation, robotium

I am searching a way I want to test login and it is not possible to write all the function with hard code values So like we have Data driven(**parametrization**) in **QTP** etc the tool fetch data from a file and keep entering and at last all our inputs are executed ..

Is it possible to do via **Roboitum** ?

Please let me know for the same.

Answer (score 0):

yes u can make a data excel file and u can fetch data from excel file

u can use

```
        File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String filename = "test.xls";
        File myfile = new File(storage, filename);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myfile);
        Workbook ws = null;
        ws = Workbook.getWorkbook(fis);
        Sheet Wsheet = ws.getSheet(SheetNum);
        String returnValue ;
        returnValue = Wsheet.getCell(ColmnNum, RowNum).getContents();
```

same as how we use Excel reading in QTP , It works for me